# allocWithZone object need to be release

Tags: objective-c

Does the object returned by allocWithZone need to be released? i.e. is it the same as alloc and new?

```
- (id) copyWithZone: (NSZone *) zone
{
Engine *engineCopy;
engineCopy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone]init];

return (engineCopy);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you still need to release it.  See the documentation for NSObject:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> If you are using managed memory (not
>   garbage collection), this method
>   retains the object before returning
>   it. The returned object has a retain
>   count of 1 and is not autoreleased.
>   The invoker of this method is
>   responsible for releasing the returned
>   object, using either release or
>   autorelease.

Comment: but in the textbook I am reading they say the following method is fine in terms of memory - see edit

Comment: See the documentation for NSCopying, http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSCopying but basically calling copyWithZone is assumed to be similar to alloc, ie it returns an object with a retain count of 1.

Comment: @TheLearner: the textbook is OK.  The fragment of code you posted is OK because `copyWithZone:`  is supposed to return an object that the caller owns.  By not releasing the object created with `allocWithZone:` before returning it, the method is effectively transferring ownership to the caller.  This is what you want.

Comment: but it will never get released

Comment: In this instance it's the code that calls copyWithZone that's responsible for releasing the object.

Answer (score 1):

`new` combines `alloc` and `init`.  It's the `alloc` that requires releasing; `allocWithZone:` should almost never be called directly (`alloc` calls it internally), and is mostly around for legacy reasons.
**Update** similarly, `copyWithZone:` should (almost) never be called directly; however, `copy` will call it implicitly.  Inside `copyWithZone:` is probably the only place where I have ever called `allocWithZone:`.